# CollectionView child added event not firing

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am using Xamarin Forms and CollectionsView.I am adding Frame child rows using SignalR. Child added event is not firing after few child is added.Is it a bug or am i doing something wrong?? I tried with CollectionView_ChildAdded event also.That one also gives this unexpected behavior

```
        <CollectionView x:Name="ItemsListView"               
            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            SelectionMode="None"
            ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepScrollOffset"  
            >
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Frame  x:Name="frame1" BackgroundColor="White" BorderColor="#F0F0F0" Padding="3" Margin="0,0,0,5" HasShadow="False"  CornerRadius="10" ChildAdded="frame1_ChildAdded">
                            <Grid HeightRequest="40" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="6*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label Grid.Column="0" x:Name="lb_TicketNumber" Text="{Binding TicketNumber}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="20,0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"  />
                                <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding DeskName}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding ServiceNameEng}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Frame>

                    </DataTemplate>
                    
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            
            </CollectionView>
```

below event stops firing after few times.

```
 private void frame1_ChildAdded(object sender, ElementEventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayAlert("Item added", "OK", "OK");
    }
```

Comment: Why are you adding to the Frame instead of adding to the ItemSource collection?

Comment: I am adding item to itemsource collection using SignalR.Its already happening..I just want to highlight added items.Multiple items can get added same time..I want to highlight all newly added item for few seconds..The above event does the job..But it stops firing after few successful firing..